# jquery dropdown close with other element

Tags: jquery, select

I am using this plugin http://vst.mn/selectordie/
for making dropdowns. But I can't figure out, how I can make another element close the menu.

I have made a fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/Lgq1grrm/1/

```
$("select").selectOrDie();

$(".closeSelect").on('click', function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

can someone help, please

Comment: Any reason to stop click event propagation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I browsed the code a little bit, but it looks like [this plugin doesn't have such a method](https://github.com/vestman/Select-or-Die/blob/501d7300798b2180076e4cd98b9915bf43105ff0/_src/selectordie.js#L533-L639).

However, we can hack it, following what happens [on the click on an option](https://github.com/vestman/Select-or-Die/blob/501d7300798b2180076e4cd98b9915bf43105ff0/_src/selectordie.js#L398-L425):

```
$("select").selectOrDie();

$(".closeSelect").on('click', function() {
    $(".selected, .sod_placeholder", "select").removeClass("selected sod_placeholder");
    $("select").removeClass("open");
});
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Lgq1grrm/2/)

Answer (score 0):

Just remove specific classes:

```
$(function(){
    $("select").selectOrDie();

    $(".closeSelect").on('click', function(e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        $(".sod_select").removeClass('focus open');
    });
});
```

### -DEMO-